# How to make a CroppedBitmap transparent?

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, transparent

I have a cropped bitmap:

```
 CroppedBitmap crop = new CroppedBitmap(rtb, new Int32Rect(MapOffset, MapOffset, BOARD_WIDTH - 1 - MapOffset, BOARD_HEIGHT - 1 - MapOffset));
```

and I need to set white to transparent. Unfortunately, this does not work (CroppedBitmap does not contain a definition for 'MakeTransparent'):

```
crop.MakeTransparent(Colors.White);
```

Anybody have any ideas / suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I found this code [How can I make all white (FFFFFFFF) pixel in an image(ImageBrush) to be transparent](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6d2380ca-4eda-4247-8892-27260fbe5517/how-can-i-make-all-white-ffffffff-pixel-in-an-imageimagebrush-to-be-transparent?forum=wpf)

But when I implement it

```
    public void SaveMainCanvas2BMP(string filename)
    {

        // Write BMP
        VisualBrush sourceBrush = new VisualBrush(MainCanvas);
        DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
        using (drawingContext)
        {
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(sourceBrush, null, new Rect(new Point(- MapOffset, - MapOffset), new Point(BOARD_WIDTH - 1 + MapOffset, BOARD_HEIGHT - 1 + MapOffset)));
        }

        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(BOARD_WIDTH - 1, BOARD_HEIGHT - 1, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
        rtb.Render(drawingVisual);

        //crops  rectangle at position (0,0).
        CroppedBitmap crop = new CroppedBitmap(rtb, new Int32Rect(0, 0, BOARD_WIDTH - 1, BOARD_HEIGHT - 1));

        WriteableBitmap writeable = new WriteableBitmap(crop);

        // Code to turn WHITE pixels TRANSPARENT
        int pixelWidth = (int)writeable.Width;
        int pixelHeight = (int)writeable.Height;
        int Stride = pixelWidth * 4;

        BitmapSource imgSource = (BitmapSource)writeable;
        byte[] pixels = new byte[pixelHeight * Stride];
        imgSource.CopyPixels(pixels, Stride, 0);
        byte TransparentByte = byte.Parse("0");
        byte Byte255 = byte.Parse("255");
        int N = pixelWidth * pixelHeight;
        //Operate the pixels directly
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            byte a = pixels[i * 4];
            byte b = pixels[i * 4 + 1];
            byte c = pixels[i * 4 + 2];
            byte d = pixels[i * 4 + 3];
            if (a == Byte255 && b == Byte255 && c == Byte255 && d == Byte255)
            {
                pixels[i * 4] = TransparentByte;
                pixels[i * 4 + 1] = TransparentByte;
                pixels[i * 4 + 2] = TransparentByte;
                pixels[i * 4 + 3] = TransparentByte;
            }
        }
        WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(pixelWidth, pixelHeight, 96, 96,
            PixelFormats.Pbgra32, BitmapPalettes.Halftone256Transparent);
        writeableBitmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, pixelWidth, pixelHeight), pixels, Stride, 0);



        //encode as BMP
        BitmapEncoder bmpEncoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();

        bmpEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(writeableBitmap));

        //save to memory stream
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        bmpEncoder.Save(ms);
        ms.Close();
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, ms.ToArray());
    }
```

It doesn't make WHITE transparent; it replaces WHITE with BLACK:

[image]

---

EDIT 
SOLUTION

The solution is over here (the problem has to do with WPF and transparency):
[Solution to transparency problem](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/65b3aedb-d036-4ef3-b7fc-8d95e410c504/how-to-make-a-croppedbitmap-transparent?forum=wpf)

Answer (score 1):

One possible variant is to create a writable bitmap from your CroppedBitmap:

```
WriteableBitmap writeable = new WriteableBitmap(cropped);
```

Then you can analyze each pixel of your bitmap and change white pixels to transparent ones. The fastest way to do it is to get the pixel buffer using the `Lock` method and then loop through the `BackBuffer` using unsafe code. The simpler but slower way is to use `CopyPixels` and `WritePixels` methods.

Comment: Do you know of a link that demonstrates how to get the pixel buffer using the Lock method and then loop through the BackBuffer using unsafe code?

Comment: There is a sample on the MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap(v=vs.110).aspx (see DrawPixel method in the example at the bottom of the page).
But it is not perfect, because they cast IntPtr to int, so it may fail on 64-bit platforms. You should can it to byte* instead and work directly with pointers. Note that you can process all bytes after a single Lock call and then call Unlock in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the way WPF handles transparency (BMPs are not the way to go, PNGs are).

Solution here:
[Solution to transparency problem](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/65b3aedb-d036-4ef3-b7fc-8d95e410c504/how-to-make-a-croppedbitmap-transparent?forum=wpf)